# Cryptography using matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, cryptography

I thought about this idea as a method of cryptography. I appreciate if someone could advice if it is wrong.

The method applies a SVD (singular value decomposition) method known in the linear algebra.

It still applies the trap-door algorithm in such way that Alice should send the public key to Bob but keeps the private key for herself. Later she will use the private key to open the message received from Bob.

Here is the sketch of the method:

1) Alice constructs a matrix $M$; consists of $m$ rows and $n$ columns, where $m$ and $n$ are large numbers and very close in the number of digits. Say (1000 x 995). The matrix entries are complex numbers.

2) Alice uses SVD to decompose $M$ yields  $M=USV^T$, where $S$ is the matrix with complex eigen values.

3) Alice shares the public key which is $U^TS^{-1}$ where $U^T$ is the transpose of $U$ and $S^{-1}$ is the inverse of $S$.

4) Bob constructs his message in the form of a column vector $Q$ with entries of natural numbers, and he performs $[QU^TS^{-1}]^T$ and gets $q^T$. Note that $q$ is reduced vector on a lower dimension space with length, m or n whichever shorter in number of digits. Bob then sends $q$ to Alice.

5) Alice retrieves $Q`$ by using; $Q`=USq$.

Because $m$ and $n$ are large but unequal in the numbers of digits, $U^TS^{-1}$ can not be a square matrix. This will not allow Eve, a spy agent, to invert it and get $US$.

Eve also, can not retrieve neither $U$ nor $S$ by multiplying $U^TS^{-1}$ by its transpose. This because when doing so, she may only get the value modulus of the complex number representing the eigen values of $S$ but she can not get argument (the phase factor).

And because $m$ and $n$ are so large, the omitting of the smaller $m-n$ number of the eigen values will not affect the round approximation $Q`$ to $Q$.

Comment: The Wikipedia page for SVD says that $S$ is a non-square diagonal matrix and that $U$ and $V$ are unitary, which would mean that their inverse and conjugate transpose are equal. It also says that $USV^T$ should be $USV^\dagger$, where $V^\dagger$ is the conjugate transpose. I'm also not sure what you mean when you say that $S$ has complex eigenvalues; $S$ isn't square, so it doesn't have eigenvalues. $S$ also doesn't have one well-defined inverse (its right and left inverses are not the same, because they produce identity matrices of different sizes).

Comment: $S$ is effectively a square matrix since all other extra eigen values along the diagonal=0. Also $S$ is the matrix where the entries are the eigen values and being not having a well defined inverse is in favor of my point that Eve can not invert it.

Comment: "effectively a square matrix" $\neq$ a square matrix, for inversion purposes. You're going to have to at least specify whether $S^{-1}$ corresponds to the left inverse or the right inverse. Along those same lines, if Eve can't invert $S$, then what makes you think that Alice can? Alice needs to invert $S$ to make the public key in the first place.

Comment: Because Eve does not have access on $S^-1$, she has only access to $U^TS^-1$ and she can not retrieve $S^-1$ from it.

Comment: $S$ is square matrix, or in my words, can be effectively a square matrix after omitting the small-values $m-n$ eigen values that represent the small redundant noise. This is similar to the dimension reduction algorithm.

Comment: But this still doesn't answer the question: how does _Alice_ invert $S$? And what "small-values" eigenvalues are you talking about? $S$ is already a rectangular diagonal matrix - all of the entries on the diagonal are already filled, all other entries are zero, and extending the diagonal to make a square matrix will just give you more zeros as eigenvalues.